# How to run gsutil command in django non-rel app

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to use gsutil command from my non-rel django gae app. I have put gsutil folder in my project directory. My code is as below:

```
    PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__)).replace('\\','/')
    p = PROJECT_PATH+"/gsutil/gsutil"
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>path>>>>>>>>>>"+str(p))
    log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>gsutil use start")

    os.system("python "+p+" cp -R gs://jatin/user2 d:/jatin/Project/GAE_django/files/")

    log.info("done")
```

But i cant download any file in my directory. It doen't return any error. IT prints both log.info() in log file. Any one can suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if you can run arbitrary shell commands from your GAE app, unless using Compute Engine. Consider using the Python API client instead: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download

Answer (score 1):

You can't run gsutil from GAE. If you want to manipulate your buckets use the [API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/). It gives you all the tools gsutil would have access to and more as its simply a wrapper for the API.